# When training a neural network to determine appropriate number of epochs should you look at validation loss or validation objective loss?

Tags: neural-networks, convergence, loss-functions

I'm currently training a basic feedforward neural network for a binary classification task. For the loss function I'm currently using logloss, but the actual objective that I'm looking to improve on is ROC AUC. I understand that you typically look for where validation loss diverges from the training loss. However, in this case while the validation loss (logloss) has diverged, the validation AUC value keeps on improving.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the **validation metric** that interests you for evaluation purposes.

The loss on the training set, on high capacity models, could reduce to zero (a point at which the model has **memorized** the training set). At this point the model has most likely **overfit**. One of the most common ways of combating overfitting is called **early stopping**. With this technique, a validation metric is monitored and when it stops dropping the training is terminated.

As for the question of which metric you should monitor, I'd suggest monitoring the metric you think best represents the performance of your model (the metric with which you'll be performing your final evaluation).